# UILocalNotification doesn't play a specific sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can't get the iPhone to play a 2 seconds long mp3 sound on notifications. I've tried with a 7 seconds long mp3 file and that works well. As far as I know there shouldn't be any restrictions on the minimum length of a notification sound.

The mp3 sounds are added to the project in the same way, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Is there any restrictions on mp3 files for UILocalNotification, which I should know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `mp3` to `caf` format as explained [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=335683), that should help.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! I found [this guide](http://www.machackpc.com/how-to-convert-a-mp3-file-to-a-caf-file-using-itunes/), which describes an easier way of converting the file.

Comment: The specific line is: /usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 {INPUT} {OUTPUT}